# Console shows error about Content Security policy and lots of failed GET requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm actually working on my first Chrome Extension and *even if it run smooth* i got a lot of error from the `get()` function i'm using to retrieve some data and an annoying error about the security of the code.

Here's a [screenshot of the console log](https://i.imgur.com/ohyir.png):
[image: Console Log]

Following there's the code involved:

### popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NGI Little Helper - Subscribes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="common/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Topics</h1>
    <div id="content">..:: Loading ::..</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

This script start making a `$.get()` to a remote web page. The content of the variable `data` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/h2z1uvRk)

```
$.get("http://gaming.ngi.it/subscription.php?do=viewsubscription", function(data) {
    var TDs = $('td[id*="td_threadtitle_"]', data);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content").html("<br/>");
        $.each( TDs, function() {
            //Removes useless elements from the source
            $('img[src="images/misc/tag.png"]', this).remove();
            $('span', this).remove(); //$('span[class="smallfont"]', this).remove();
            $('div[class="smallfont"]', this).remove();
            $('img[src="images/buttons/firstnew.gif"]', this).attr('src', '/img/icons/comment.gif');
            $('a[style="font-weight:bold"]', this).removeAttr("style");
            //Modify the lenght of the strings
            if ($("a[id^='thread_title_']", this).text().length > 35) {
                $("a[id^='thread_title_']", this).text( $("a[id^='thread_title_']", this).text().substring(0, 30) + " [...]" );
            }
            //Modify the URL from relative to absolute and add the target="_newtab"
            $("a[id^='thread_']", this).attr('href', "http://gaming.ngi.it/"+ $("a[id^='thread_']", this).attr('href'));
            $("a[id^='thread_']", this).attr('target', "_newtab");
            //Send the HTML modified to the popup window
            $("#content").html($("#content").html() + $('div', this).wrap("<span></span>").parent().html() +"<br/>" );
        });
    });
});
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/sBjhL0DP) you can find the HTML after all the manipulation from jquery.

Honestly i cannot understand why these error show, especially the one related to the security. I've not used any inline code in my popup.html.

### Manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "NGI Little Helper",
    "version": "0.8.5",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Extension per gli Utenti del forum gaming.ngi.it",
    "options_page": "fancy-settings/source/index.html",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/logo16.png",
        "48": "img/logo48.png",
        "128": "img/logo128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://gaming.ngi.it/*"],
        "js": ["common/jquery.js", "logo_changer/logo_change.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Visualizza Subscriptions"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://gaming.ngi.it/*"
    ]
}
```

The following is a piece of HTML code that will be rendered into the popup window after all the manipulation. All the `div` is similar to this, just the url changes:

```
<div>

            <a href="http://gaming.ngi.it/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=555954" id="thread_gotonew_555954" target="_newtab"><img class="inlineimg" src="/img/icons/comment.gif" alt="Go to first new post" border="0"></a>




            <a href="http://gaming.ngi.it/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=555954" id="thread_title_555954" target="_newtab">[All Gamez] [Frozen Synapse] S [...]</a>

        </div>
```

If needed i can provide the full source code.

Comment: Any chance you could link to a version of the screenshot that's large enough to actually be readable? It's not much use to the question if I can't read any of the text.

Comment: Just edited the question adding a link to the high resolution :)
check the text "Here's a screenshot of the console log:". It's clickable now.

Comment: Can you share your manifest.json file? Maybe there is something wrong with `content_security_policy` field.

Comment: Added the code of manifest.json

Comment: Hint: The scraped page may contain `<script>` blocks and/or inline event handlers. Hint 2: The page references images via relative URLs.

Comment: @RobW that's a good point. It's the subscription page of a vbulletin board. There's a way i can prevent all that console error? i'm not a junior programmer but i'm new with jquery.
The .get() doesn't just store the result into a variable (data)?
Why the console act like i'm trying to render the content obtained?

Comment: @theCrius Because you *are* rendering (parts of) the response. You're apparently looping through a set of cells, selecting a `<div>` element, concatenating the HTML, etc. (it's the line after `//Send the HTML modified to the popup window`).

Comment: @RobW I'll add an example of what a rendered `<div>` will contains into the question. As you can see, there is no inline javascript or any image.
I store the content of `$.get()` inside the variable `TD` filtering with the selector all the `<td>` with a specific `id`.
Then i'll cycle through and begin to modify the html removing useless `<img>` and `<span>`. Only after all of this process i render the content that you can now see at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Note: i've updated the popup.js just to reflect a better "logical" optimization just using a single `.each()` to manipulate the html get from the scraped web page.
Nothing change as result of course.

Comment: Can you store the value of `data` in a variable, and put it on http://pastebin.com/ or http://pastie.org/?

Comment: @RobW for sure. I'll add the link to the question too: [link](http://pastebin.com/pvrmymsq)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with the easiest problem:

### Refused to execute inline script because ...

`$('div', this)` selects all `<div>` elements within a `<td>`. In the [source code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pvrmymsq) you provided, the following event handler can be found:

```
<div class="smallfont">
    <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=47995', '_self')">K4raMong</span>
</div>
```

By the default [Content Security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), this is forbidden. To get rid off the error, just remove the attribute before inserting it in the document:

```
element.removeAttribute('onclick'); // in jQuery: $element.removeAttr('onclick');
```

## Why are these images loaded? I didn't put them in the document

Before jQuery/JavaScript can manipulate DOM, it must be parsed first. In your code, this work is implicitly done at the `var TDs = $(.., data)`. line. This parsing is approximately equal to:

```
var dummy = document.createElement('div'); // Container
dummy.innerHTML = data;
```

Ever heard about preloading images? That is a useful feature to cache images, so that they're ready when needed. This can be done using `(new Image).src='...';`. The created `<img>` element doesn't have to be inserted in the document.

In your case, this is undesired behaviour, because these images are looked up in your extension. This is caused by the fact that your web page makes use of *relative URLs*, rather than absolute ones. When using relative URLs, the expected location of the resources depends on the location of the current document.

### How to fix it

**Do *not* use jQuery**. Since you're writing a Chrome extension, you do not need to worry about cross-browser compatibility. jQuery uses the `innerHTML` trick to parse HTML, which failed, as I've previously shown.

JavaScript has the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) object, which can be used as follows since Chrome 30:

```
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
```

You can skip the manual conversion from string to document using the `responseType` property, as shown below.

#### Arriving at the solution

As you already know, cross-site requests are possible in Chrome extensions, provided that the URL is correctly added to the `permissions` section in the manifest file. We're going to use a feature introduced in XMLHttpRequest level 2, namely the [`responseType` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest).

```
// Fetching data
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://gaming.ngi.it/subscription.php?do=viewsubscription');
xhr.onload = function() {
    var doc = xhr.response;
    // Now, you can use jQuery, since the string has been parsed.
    ...
};
xhr.responseType = 'document'; // Chrome 18+
xhr.send();
```

You can easily rewrite your code to use native DOM and JavaScript instead of jQuery. Most use jQuery for the selector engine, but most often, it can also be implemented using [`element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll). After getting the document using `var doc = xhr.response;`, do the following:

```
var TDs = doc.querySelectorAll('td[id*="td_threadtitle_"]');
var html = '';
[].forEach.call(TDs, function(td) {
    // etc, etc. Do your job
});
```

Do you see `var html = '';`? That's good practice, regardless of whether you're using jQuery or not. Never do `element.innerHTML += ...;` or even worse `$element.html($element.html() + ...);` in a loop. The browser will have a hard time with rendering it over and over again, and you -as a user- notice performance degradation.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The hint was really useful :)

Comment: Damn, this is amazing. Just ran into jQuery's inability to handle parsing a page complete with <html>, <head>, and <body> tags, and this was the solution for Chrome...how does Chrome's DOM Parser not accept the text/html mime type? Arggg.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility), `DOMParser` works with HTML starting with Chrome 30.

Comment: @Xan Updated answer. I still suggest to use `responseType='document'` though. The DOMParser was only mentioned to show how to fix the general problem of converting a string to a DOM using vanilla JS instead of jQuery. I did not fix the bug by the way, I just verified that the bug has been fixed and updated the crbug ticker and documentation on MDN.