# How to open and use the same tab for several different link in popup.html

Tags: jquery, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I'm actually working on my first Chrome Extension and i need to improve some function.
Actually i'm new of chrome extensions and can't figure out how i can manage tabs.

Actually the extension open a popup window with a list of link catched from a remote web page. Every link open a new tab with the right content inside.

My goal is to open a tab and, for every link, use that single tab (if the tab created is closed, i can open a new tab a continue to use that). I suppose i can create a new tab and refer to it by and ID assigned but i can't figure out how really write the correct code.

Following there's the code involved:

### popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NGI Little Helper - Subscribes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="common/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Topics</h1>
    <div id="content">..:: Loading ::..</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```
$.get("http://gaming.ngi.it/subscription.php?do=viewsubscription", function(data) {
    var TDs = $('td[id^="td_threadtitle_"]', data);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content").html("<br/>");
        $.each( TDs, function() {
            //Removes useless elements from the source
            $('img[src="images/misc/tag.png"]', this).remove();
            $('span', this).remove(); //$('span[class="smallfont"]', this).remove();
            $('div[class="smallfont"]', this).remove();
            $('img[src="images/buttons/firstnew.gif"]', this).attr('src', '/img/icons/comment.gif');
            $('a[style="font-weight:bold"]', this).removeAttr("style");
            //Modify the lenght of the strings
            if ($("a[id^='thread_title_']", this).text().length > 35) {
                $("a[id^='thread_title_']", this).text( $("a[id^='thread_title_']", this).text().substring(0, 30) + " [...]" );
            }
            //Modify the URL from relative to absolute and add the target="_newtab"
            $("a[id^='thread_']", this).attr('href', "http://gaming.ngi.it/"+ $("a[id^='thread_']", this).attr('href'));
            $("a[id^='thread_']", this).attr('target', "_newtab");
            //Send the HTML modified to the popup window
            $("#content").html($("#content").html() + $('div', this).wrap("<span></span>").parent().html() +"<br/>" );
        });
    });
});
```

### Manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "NGI Little Helper",
    "version": "0.8.5",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Extension per gli Utenti del forum gaming.ngi.it",
    "options_page": "fancy-settings/source/index.html",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/logo16.png",
        "48": "img/logo48.png",
        "128": "img/logo128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://gaming.ngi.it/*"],
        "js": ["common/jquery.js", "logo_changer/logo_change.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Visualizza Subscriptions"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://gaming.ngi.it/*"
    ]
}
```

The following is a piece of HTML code that will be rendered into the popup window after all the manipulation. Any div is similar to this one, except the link changes of course:

```
<div>

            <a href="http://gaming.ngi.it/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=555954" id="thread_gotonew_555954" target="_newtab"><img class="inlineimg" src="/img/icons/comment.gif" alt="Go to first new post" border="0"></a>




            <a href="http://gaming.ngi.it/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=555954" id="thread_title_555954" target="_newtab">[All Gamez] [Frozen Synapse] S [...]</a>

        </div>
```

If needed i can provide the full source code.

Comment: The code in this question is exactely the same as [the one in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089752/console-shows-error-about-content-security-policy-and-lots-of-failed-get-request). Most of the code is not relevant to this question. I suggest to remove most of the unrelated code, and start the question with something like "In my [previous question link], I asked .... Now, I need to ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to recycle existing tabs is to use the [`chrome.tabs.query()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) method. Check, if there is a tab with URL that matches a pattern (e.g. `http://gaming.ngi.it/*`). If it exists, open the URL in it. If not, open a new tab. Like this:

```
var match = 'http://gaming.ngi.it/*';
var url = 'http://gaming.ngi.it/showthread.php?goto=newpost&amp;t=555954';

chrome.tabs.query({url : match}, function (foundTabs) {
    if (foundTabs[0]) {
        chrome.tabs.update(foundTabs[0].id, {
            active : true,
            url : url
        });
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.create({url : url});
    }
});
```

I wrote a simple reusable function [`reuseTab()` for Chrome](https://github.com/fczbkk/chrome-extension-snippets/blob/master/js/reuse-tab.js), it is hosted in GitHub and contains detailed comments with explanation of how everything works. Feel free to check it out and use it.