# Chrome Extension doesn't considers optionvalue until reloaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, local-storage

I'm working on my first Chrome Extension. [After learning some interesting notions about jquery i've moved to raw javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089752/console-shows-error-about-content-security-policy-and-lots-of-failed-get-request) thanks to "Rob W".

Actually the extension do an XMLHttpRequest to a remote page with some parameters and, after manipulating the result, render an html list into the popup window.

Now everything is up and running so i'm moving to add some option.
The first one was "how many elements you want to load" to set a limit to the element of the list.

I'm using fancy-setting to manage my options and here's the problem.

The extension act like there's a "cache" about the local storage settings.
If i do not set anything and perform a clean installation of the extension, the default number of element is loaded correctly.

If i change the value. I need to reload the extension to see the change.
Only if a remove the setting i see the extension work as intended immediately.

Now, i'm going a little more into specific information.

This is the popup.js script:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'gpmeGetOptions'}, function(theOptions) {
    //Load the limit for topic shown
    console.log('NGI-LH -> Received NGI "max_topic_shown" setting ('+theOptions.max_topic_shown+')');
    //Initializing the async connection
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://gaming.ngi.it/subscription.php?do=viewsubscription&pp='+theOptions.max_topic_shown+'&folderid=all&sort=lastpost&order=desc');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var html = "<ul>";
        var doc = xhr.response;
        var TDs = doc.querySelectorAll('td[id*="td_threadtitle_"]');
        [].forEach.call(TDs, function(td) {
            //Removes useless elements from the source
            var tag = td.querySelector('img[src="images/misc/tag.png"]'); (tag != null) ? tag.parentNode.removeChild(tag) : false;
            var div_small_font = td.querySelector('div[class="smallfont"]'); (small_font != null ) ? small_font.parentNode.removeChild(small_font) : false;
            var span_small_font = td.querySelector('span[class="smallfont"]'); (small_font != null ) ? small_font.parentNode.removeChild(small_font) : false;
            var span = td.querySelector('span'); (span != null ) ? span.parentNode.removeChild(span) : false;
            //Change the look of some elements
            var firstnew = td.querySelector('img[src="images/buttons/firstnew.gif"]'); (firstnew != null ) ? firstnew.src = "/img/icons/comment.gif" : false;
            var boldtext = td.querySelector('a[style="font-weight:bold"]'); (boldtext != null ) ? boldtext.style.fontWeight = "normal" : false;
            //Modify the lenght of the strings
            var lenght_str = td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_title_"]');
            if (lenght_str.textContent.length > 40) {
                lenght_str.textContent = lenght_str.textContent.substring(0, 40);
                lenght_str.innerHTML += "<span style='font-size: 6pt'> [...]</span>";
            }
            //Removes "Poll:" and Tabulation from the strings
            td.querySelector('div').innerHTML = td.querySelector('div').innerHTML.replace(/(Poll)+(:)/g, '');
            //Modify the URL from relative to absolute and add the target="_newtab" for the ICON
            (td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_title"]') != null) ? td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_title"]').href += "&goto=newpost" : false;
            (td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_goto"]') != null) ? td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_goto"]').href += "&goto=newpost": false;
            (td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_title"]') != null) ? td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_title"]').target = "_newtab": false;
            (td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_goto"]') != null) ? td.querySelector('a[id^="thread_goto"]').target = "_newtab": false;

            //Store the td into the main 'html' variable
            html += "<li>"+td.innerHTML+"</li>";
    //      console.log(td);
        });
        html += "</ul>";
        //Send the html variable to the popup window
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html.toString();
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'document'; // Chrome 18+
    xhr.send();
});
```

Following the background.js (the html just load /fancy-settings/source/lib/store.js and this script as Fancy-Setting How-To explains)

```
//Initialization fancy-settings
var settings = new Store("settings", {
    "old_logo": false,
    "max_topic_shown": "10"
});
//Load settings
var settings = settings.toObject();

//Listener who send back the settings
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == 'gpmeGetOptions') {
        sendResponse(settings);
    }
});
```

The console.log show the value as it has been cached, as i said.
If i set the value to "20", It remain default until i reload the extension.
If i change it to 30, it remain at 20 until i reload the extension.

If something more is needed, just ask. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a conceptual misunderstanding. The `background.js` script in a Chrome Extension is loaded once and continues to run until either the extension or the Chrome Browser is restarted.

This means in your current code the `settings` variable value is loaded only when the extension first starts. In order to access values that have been updated since the extension is loaded the `settings` variable value in `background.js` must be reloaded.

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. The simplest is to move the `settings` related code into the `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` callback function in `background.js`. This is also the most inefficient solution, as settings are reloaded every request whether they have actually been updated or not.

A better solution would be to reload the `settings` value in `background.js` only when the values are updated in the options page. This uses the persistence, or caching, of the settings variable to your advantage. You'll have to check the documentation for implementation details, but the idea would be to send a message from the options page to the `background.js` page, telling it to update `settings` after the new settings have been stored.

As an unrelated aside, the `var` keyword in the line `var settings = settings.toObject();` is not needed. There is no need to redeclare the variable, it is already declared above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Chris. I'll check later on (actually overloaded at work) and give you an 'accepted answer' asap :)