# Handle Relative Image Paths ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a small Google chrome extension that screen scrapes a certain website. The problem is that because that website uses relative paths the links become broken and I get lots of errors like this:

```
GET chrome-extension://higopdenpioddpmobbehnbcadeenihic/html/images/ico_aAO.gif
GET chrome-extension://higopdenpioddpmobbehnbcadeenihic/html/images/ico_dAO.gif
```

Is there any way to avoid these errors?

The code I'm using for making the GET call is:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: searchUrl,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'pal': query
        },
        success: function() {
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to get the images via Ajax, and in doing so accidentally making a request for an image in the Chrome extension?

Comment: I have the same problem. The response has link to image, but I only parse the response HTML text. However jQuery still try to fetch those images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to not use jQuery to parse the document. You can use `jQuery.ajax` if you want to, but do not use `$` to parse the result.

Read the answer to [Console shows error about Content Security policy and lots of failed GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12100954/938089?console-shows-error-about-content-security-policy-and-lots-of-failed-get-request) to understand and solve your problem.

The answer strongly recommends to use vanilla JavaScript. If you want to use jQuery nevertheless, use the following DOM parsing method:

```
// responseText is a string, for example from calling jQuery.ajax
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = responseText;
var $doc = $(doc);
// Enjoy the parsed document without errors!
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use jQuery or $ to make the ajax call, what did the trick was creating the intermediate document. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoPenetra I meant jQuery should not be used to parse the HTML, as in `$('<html>result possibly containing <img src="whatever.png">')`. It's fine to use jQuery for getting the response, but parse the HTML using something else, such as the method shown in my answer.