# jQuery on external text requesting images

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that uses jquery to parse the source of a page for specific things. In example I'm looking through Wikipedia to get the categories.

I get the source of the page via

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: "chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: 'getContentText', source: document.body.innerHTML, location: window.location});"
}, function() {
    if (chrome.extension.lastError)
         console.log(chrome.extension.lastError.message);
});
```

I am then listening for this message (successfully) and then use jquery to parse the `source` key of the object, like so

```
if (request.action == "getContentText")
{
    //console.log(request.source);
    $('#mw-normal-catlinks > ul > li > a', request.source).each(function()
    {
        console.log("category", $(this).html());
    });
}
```

This works as expected and logs a list of all the category links innerHTML. However the issue happens from that jQuery selector that it tries to load the images that are contained in `request.source`. This results in errors such as

`GET chrome-extension://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Padlock-silver.svg/20px-Padlock-silver.svg.png net::ERR_FAILED`

These are valid links, however they are being called (unneeded) from my extension with the `chrome-extension://` prefix (which is invalid). I'm not sure why jquery would try to evaluate/request images from within source using a selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is happening because Wikipedia uses relative paths on their images (instead of https:// or http://, simply // - so the content loaded is relative to the server). The requests are being made by jQuery and you can see [here how to fix this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174905/handle-relative-image-paths-ajax) (in future, please make sure to search SO more thoroughly).

Comment: The problem is I don't want (or need) the images. I'm just going for the category <a> innerHTML, which is successfully captured by that Jquery selector. I just want to get rid of the errors/requests to those images

Comment: You could use $.fn.text() instead of $.fn.html(). text() will only get the inner text without the HTML elements. Furthermore simply try removing the img from the response: $('img', request.source).remove():

Comment: Trying a combination of all of your answers did not work. I'm still unsure why jquery is even requesting the images at all. Even just doing a request like `$('#mw-normal-catlinks > ul > li > a', request.source)` will cause those errors to arise

Comment: Where did you put the remove() line?

Comment: where `//console.log(request.source);` is now

Comment: Maybe $('img', request.source).attr('src', '') will do the trick (before the each loop).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74009/discussion-between-timonwimmer-and-frozenfire).

Answer (score 1):

A huge thank you to @timonwimmer for helping me in the chat. We both happened to find different solutions at the same time.

My solution was to use a regex to remove any occurances of the images. Via

`var source = request.source.replace(/.*?\.wikimedia\.org\/.*?/g, "");`

His was an answer on stack overflow already, that was derived from another answer. If you are interested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797260/4330669) works perfectly

Comment: Your solution is band-aid, and will still cause issues for resources from other URLs. I strongly suggest to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089752/console-shows-error-about-content-security-policy-and-lots-of-failed-get-request/12100954#12100954 for the cause of these errors, and how you should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you give jQuery a string with a complete element declaration it actually generates a new DOM element, similar to calling `document.createElement(tagName)` and setting all of the attributes. 
For instance: `var $newEl = $("<p>test</p>")` or in your case `img` tag elements with `$("<img/>")`. That would get parsed and created as a new DOM HTML element and wrapped by jQuery so you can query it.

Since you *are* passing a complete and valid HTML string, it is parsing it into an actual DOM first. This is because jQuery uses the built in underlying `document.querySelector` methods and they act on the DOM not on strings -- think of the DOM as a database with indexes for id and class and attributes for querying. For instance, [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) cannot perform queries on a raw JSON string, it needs to first process the JSON into BSON and index it all and the queries are performed on that.

Your problem is less with jQuery and more so with how elements are created and what happens when attributes change for those elements. For instance, when the `img` elements are created with `document.createElement('img')` and then the `src` attribute is set with `imgElement.src = "link to image"` this automatically triggers the load for the image at location `src`.

You can test this out for yourself by running this in your JavaScript Developer Console:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "broken-link";
```

Notice that this will likely show and errors in your console after running stating that the image cannot be found.

So what you want, to ensure so it does not resolve the image's `src`, is to either 
1) apply jQuery on an existing DOM (`document.body`, etc), or 
2) let it parse and evaluate the string into a DOM and clean the string before hand (remove the `img` tags using Regex or something). Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230103/2578205 for removing HTML tags from string.

Hope it works out!