# jQuery.get() returns errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I use `$.get` function to get some html from exetrnal website in my chrome extension:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var someImgs= $(data).find('img[width="90"]').parent();
});
```

But I see such errors in my console:

[image]
`chrome-extension://nqzxdldmasxchnkgibeedilpknlbndiho/files/image.png` 
I don't use any images in my extension, and I know this is link to image on exetrnal website.

**What I tried:**

1. wrap `$.get()` function into `try-catch`
2. handle error using `$.ajaxError()`
3. replace relevant links *`/files/image.png`* to full path: *`http://website/files/image.png`* using `data.replace()`
4. run example code in jsFiddle: errors are the same but despite of that code continiues running.

No ideas now. What I do wrong?

**UPD:** Error doesn't occur when I don't touch to `data`. When inside `$.get` I simple type `console.log(data)` there are no errors

**UPD2:** I also tried to download all the images whcih are mentioned in error messages and put them in the same path in my extension as on external website

**UPD3:** As it was mentioned in comments, images from remote website are reffering to relative paths. So I tried to replace relative paths in 'src' attribute to full, using this code:

```
var data = data.replace('/sites/default/', 'http://website/sites/default/');
```

As you guess - result is the same, same errors.

**UPD4:** Seems like replacement wasn't successful. I checked the above replacement and it says nothing changed:

```
console.log(data.indexOf('src="/sites/default/')); //returns integer
```

**So, actually it was solved** by downloading remote images to my extension foled. Little 'nasty' way but the only workable. Thanks to all the commentators that helped me to find out the source of problem.

Comment: what is the error? 404/500 etc

Comment: @ArunPJohny http://pastexen.com/i/My1wxfyxIf.png

Comment: Are you sure the error is caused by the $.get? Doesn't it occur when you comment out the $.get?

Comment: That error is definitely not caused by your code.

Comment: Error doesn't occur when I don't touch to `data`. When inside `$.get` I simple type `console.log(data)` there are no errors

Comment: what is the result if you give complete url

Comment: @ArunPJohny what do you mean?

Comment: When I run this code in JsFiddle it says 404 not found - http://pastexen.com/i/iZD4XnflD7.png

Comment: @VladGolubev - Um, is `url` in `$.get(url` a valid url?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 of course. it works fine in jsfiddle (despite of same errors)

Comment: @VladGolubev - Can you show the whole error message, because right now I don't understand what the problem is. It seems like the reason the error occurred is because the image simply doesn't exist. And also what is `url`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 http://pastexen.com/i/3XMK9fVt80.png but despite of that errors same code in jsFiddle works perfectly.

Comment: @VladGolubev - You can go to the Developer Tools, click on network, click on the black dot, then send the request. See if the Status Code is `404` or `204`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  - http://pastexen.com/i/F4d9R230vN.png

Comment: @VladGolubev - You have to click on the file names...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - http://i.imgur.com/8r1EDH3.gif

Comment: @VladGolubev - That means the file does not exist. Have you tried reloading your extension after putting in the files?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I've simply downloaded them all and put to the same path as on website. It works... but I don't know yet what has occured an error.. Thanks to everybody. Дet us leave this question

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** On second look it appears that the html of the page at `url` contains images with relative file paths (like `/files/menu_banners/ktc_apple.png`), but when you interpret it and treat it with jQuery as a DOM object, it fails to load them because their urls are now interpreted as relative to the extension (cross-origin restrictions still apply, but that's not the issue since you've edited the manifest)

--

You are trying to make a cross-origin request, but jQuery isn't aware of a correct API to use when included in an extension and that is why it's failing. You can read more about [XHR in Google Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html); you basically need to allow cross-domain access to your website URL:

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html)
>   section of the [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) file, the extension can request access to
>   remote servers outside of its origin:
>
> ```
> //manifest.json
> {
>   "name": "My extension",
>   ...
>   "permissions": [
>     "http://www.google.com/"
>   ],
>   ...
> }
> ```

So in your manifest you should include your `http://website` url, or use a wildcard `http://*/` and allow access to any domain (handy in dev, terrible idea security-wise in production)

Comment: I use `"<all_urls>"` in permissions section but result is the same

Comment: @o.v. - The error message doesn't match. If it's because of SOP then the error message would be `XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Note: `Permission 'http://*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.`

Comment: As Vlad mentioned, `http://*` is not a valid url pattern. It should be `http://*/*`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: docos refer to `http://*/`, must have lost that last slash when copying. Any path information is ignored because this is not a content script

Comment: Reply to your edit: yes, it true and I knew this. As I already mentioned in my question above (in "Whant I've tried" paragraph)I tried to replace relative urls to full path but that doesn't help me. So I've simply downloaded that damned images and put them in my extension folder.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: good point about the error messages, I'm used to chrome swallowing specifics so I've just assumed CORS right away when I saw the protocol. Looks like the errors don't even occur in javascript, but in the page DOM; same would happen in jsfiddle etc.

Comment: @VladGolubev: hmm, with the correct CORS policy you should be able to refer to the images by explicitly using their full url. Can you update the question with the code showing what you do with the images?

Comment: I simply added this line inside `$.get` to replace all relative links to full: `var data = data.replace('/sites/default/', 'http://www.ktc-ua.com/sites/default/');`
`data` contains entire html code of a page which is returned by $.get

Comment: @VladGolubev: well, I get 404 for [replaced urls](http://www.ktc-ua.com/sites/default/files/menu_banners/ktc_apple.png) as well, any chance you're missing a non-`80` port from the url?

Comment: @o.v. change `menu_banners` to `menu_baners` in url. it's valid.

Comment: @o.v. see upd4 in my question. seems like replacement failed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45074/discussion-between-o-v-and-vlad-golubev)

Comment: @o.v. Could you vote to close the question as a duplicate? The question has already been covered before in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089752/console-shows-error-about-content-security-policy-and-lots-of-failed-get-request