# XMLHttpRequest getting Errors and Security Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a code similar to the simplified one below to search through several pages of posts on a forum website and then list the links in console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

for(i = 0; i <= 735; i += 15) {
    var xhrs = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrs.open("get", 'http://fakeURL.com/' + i, true);
    xhrs.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4) 
        {
            $(this.responseText).find('a').each(function()
            {           
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                console.log(url);                                               
            });
        }
    }
    xhrs.send();
}

}
```

The problem is that sometimes I'll get errors like this in console:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "dailydawdle.com/".`

`Error: GET http://puu.sh/4Ueom.png 404 (Not Found)        4Ueom.png:1`

`Error: GET http://thisUrlIsTooLong.jpg 403 (Forbidden)    cellphonebuyers large verge super wide.jpg:1`

These errors usually don't stop the code from finishing the list of urls, but one time it exited the webpage and went to a red screen in chrome that said something like 'security error'.

1. Why do these errors occur and how do I stop them?

Even if I only search each page for links that begin with a certain string I get these errors. I'm saying that even if I replace `find('a')` with `find("a[href^='http://forum.posts/']")` so that only the forum's links are searched through, I still get errors with outsider website links (posted by people in the forum probably) and sometimes a red warning page that says 'security error'.

2. Why am I getting errors on links that don't even begin with the string I specified to search for?

Comment: I would first of all question the validity of a tight loop doing ajax. Instead execute the NEXT fetch in the success of the previous

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12100954/938089, below the section "Why are these images loaded? I didn't put them in the document".

Comment: Those are serverside errors, how would we know what causes them?!

Comment: @RobW Disregard my last comment. It was false so I deleted it. The ACTUAL problem is that after implementing `xhrs.onload = function() {var doc2 = xhrs.response; //then a bunch of jQuery}` and `xhrs.responseType = 'document';` into my For-Loop code, it's only showing that the loop's final iteration occurs (which is when `i` is 0). Not sure why.

Comment: Here's a link to the new question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205592/xmlhttprequest-domparser-in-for-loop-returns-only-last-iteration)