# Execute callback at end of for-loop XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, callback, xmlhttprequest

This code loops through several webpages, finds links on each page, and puts those links into an array called `linksArray`. I've tried to execute a callback when the for-loop is on its last iteration (when x =45) and the jQuery `find().each` has finished searching through all of the last page for links.

For some reason, I'm not getting links from the very last page (http://fakeURL.com/45). It seems that the callback function executes before the for-loop has gone through every webpage. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
function linkSearch(callback)
{

    for(i = 0; i <= 45; i += 1) 
    {   
        ajaxCall(i);
    }

    var i;
    var linksArray = [];
    function ajaxCall (x)
    {
        var xhrs = new XMLHttpRequest();                                    
        xhrs.open("get", 'http://fakeURL.com/' + x, true);
        xhrs.onload = function()
        {       
            var doc = xhrs.response;
            var len = $(doc).length;    //will be used in telling when .each has gotten to the end of a page
            $(doc).find("a[href^='http://linksFromEachPage.com/links']").each(function(index, element)
            {
                //below is how I'm trying to callback the linksArray when the for-loop is on its last iteration and .each has finished on the last page
                thisVal = $(this).val();
                if (x == 45)
                {
                    if(parseInt(thisVal) != 0) 
                    {
                        if (index == len - 1) 
                        {
                            if($(doc).ajaxComplete)
                            {
                                callback(linksArray);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                linksArray[x] = url;
            });
        }
        xhrs.responseType = 'document';
        xhrs.send();
    }

}

//and below is where the callback is called
linkSearch(function(theArray) 
{
    console.log(theArray);
});
```

Comment: Because the ajax call is async, you need to know when the last callback is called.  If you're going to use plain JS for it (and not use any of the helpful libraries with promises support), then you can probably just maintain a counter for when you get the last callback call (the 46th one in your implementation).

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought what I'm doing is already pretty much a counter. I don't know how to make a counter that would do anything different than what I have now.

Comment: What you're doing is far too complicated to easily follow (and likely way more complicated than need be).  For starters, it appears that you're only checking for the end when processing the response from the 46th request (x == 45), but that's definitely not right because your responses are not guaranteed in any specific order so you have to check when you've collected 46 responses, not when you're processing the response to the 46th request.  Do you understand the difference between those?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I understand now. Thanks. So instead of `if (x == 45)`, I should have a separate variable that adds one for each page that is passed, and check when *that* variable reaches the total number of pages. I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added a counter and for some reason it still doesn't show links from the last page.

Comment: The question is tagged jquery... if you're already using jquery why not use [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)..? look into [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: Are you counting to 46? which is 0 to 45 inclusive.  I also don't know what you're trying to accomplish with `if($(doc).ajaxComplete)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I'm counting 46. Ya and I don't think I need the .ajaxComplete part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is tagged with jQuery, here's a version of your code that uses jQuery for the ajax call and jQuery promises to keep track of when they are all done.

```js
function linkSearch(callback) {
    var i, promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 45; i++) {   
        promises.push(
           $.get({url:'http://fakeURL.com/' + i, dataType:'xml'})
        );
    }
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        var linksArray = [];
        // process all results here
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            $(arguments[i][0])
            .find("a[href^='http://linksFromEachPage.com/links']")
            .each(function(index, element) {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                linksArray.push(url);
            });
        }
        callback(linksArray);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing was executed within `$(arguments[i]).find("a[href^='http://linksFromEachPage.com/links']").each(function(index, element) {`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Farad - Do a `console.log(arguments.length)` and `console.log(arguments[i])` to see what the data is.  It might be that you need `arguments[i][0]` instead, as the jQuery doc is a bit confusing on this topic and I don't have runnable code to look at it in the debugger.

Comment: Ok I did that. `arguments.length` was always 46, and `arguments[i]` was each page of HTML that corresponded to which `i` it was on. Oh sweet it worked after I made it `arguments[i][0]`. That's awesome. It's just a lot slower than the code I had before, but at least all the links are in order.

Comment: Nevermind, it's not actually slower. I forgot to remove `console.log(arguments[i]);`, which is what made it slow.

Comment: I've run into a new problem. There are images being loaded that I don't want. In my original code, this was avoided by having `xhrs.responseType = 'document';` See [stackoverflow.com/a/12100954/938089](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12100954/938089), below the section "Why are these images loaded? I didn't put them in the document". Idk how I would apply that solution to this code.

Comment: I fixed the above problem by modifying the `promises.push` line to look like this: `promises.push($.get('http://fakeURL.com/' + i, undefined, undefined, "xml"));`

Comment: @Farad - since it looks like you may be new to StackOverflow, do you understand that when someone helps you solve their problem, you can vote their answer as the "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This rewards the person providing the answer and rewards you for following the proper procedure - earning both some reputation points here.

Comment: Now I'm having an issue with the array not displaying at all if the max `i` of 45 is raised to like 370. The only difference is it has to load through a lot more pages and search through a lot more HTML. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @Farad - you probably can't launch 370 Ajax calls all at the same time.  You will probably have to change the code to launch them in groups of 20 or so.  If you need help with how to do that, please ask a new question about that as that is a somewhat different problem.  You probably want to add an error handler to `$.when()` (second argument to `$.when(...).then(fSucess, fError)`) so you get a callback when there's an error too.